# How to Specify The Partition According to Which a CROSS JOIN UNNEST Clause Should be Applied?

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena, cross-join, unnest

Here is what I am trying to perform with Presto/AWS Athena. I'd be glad to get your remarks/explanations on the following.

I have a table called activity_table

```
| member_id | arrays_of_distinct_days_of_activity |
```

where

- member_id is VARCHAR and
- arrays_of_distinct_days_of_activity is an ARRAY of DATE(s)

This table includes some 150 million distinct member_id, and each member_id ***has it's own unique row.***

I am trying to perform:

```
SELECT member_id,arrays_of_distinct_days_of_activity,dt
FROM activity_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(sequence(date '2019-07-01',date '2019-07-15',interval '1' day)) AS T(dt)
```

but it results in a very long time.

Two questions:

1. Is it true that the very long calculation time results from Presto/Athena's checking for all combinations of the couple (member_id,arrays_of_distinct_days_of_activity) in order to CROSS JOIN with the UNNEST() array?
2. If yes, and since each member_id ***has a row of its own***, is there a way to specify to Presto/Athena that the CROSS JOIN should not be performed according to the combinations of ***(member_id,arrays_of_distinct_days_of_activity)***, but ***only by with the column member_id***?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your CROSS JOIN returns 150,000,000 * 15 rows, i.e. each row once for each day in your sequence.

Comment: yes. Thus I wonder if there is a way to specify to Athena that it does not need to double check this by going through all combinations of  of the two columns? which I believe is what takes much time.

A means to bypass this would be to cross join with the unnest() and the member_id ONLY and then left join the output table with the activity_table to bring the arrays_of_distinct_days_of_activity column...but it's clearly not elegant and uses two JOINs instead of one.

Comment: But then you join 150,000,000 * 15 rows and 2,250,000,000 * 1 rows for the 2nd join, why should this be faster?

Comment: My assumption is that the time consuming operation is: check the unique combinations between the two columns before CROSS JOIN. Is my hypothesis Wrong?

If not, I want to know if I can specify directly (with a command) according to which column the CROSS JOIN should be operated.

Comment: I don't even understand your hypothesis. A Cross Join doesn't care about uniqueness or the number of columns, it simply returns all possible combinations.

Comment: Your remark partially answers me. SO there no such step as: calculating all possible combinations between the two columns before making the cross product. Thanks!

Comment: UNNEST performance was improved in Presto 316 (https://github.com/prestosql/presto/pull/901). While Athena is based on Presto .172, you can easily run Presto on AWS yourself or use Starburst Presto service for AWS: https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/. (I'm from Starburst.)